# How can i extract data from a .txt file and store it in 2 separate variables?

Tags: python

I would like to extract data from a .txt() file, and then be able to store the two different items (wooden bow and 10) in two separate variables. For example:

```
var1 = 'wooden bow'
var2 = 10
```

and the .txt file would look like this:

```
wooden bow, 10
```

how would i go about this?

Comment: You could read this file in as a `csv` file.

Comment: how would i do that? i am a beginner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the file for reading, then iterate over the lines, reading the vars' values out with `.split()`

```py
with open("myfile.txt") as fh:  # fh is now a file-like object
    for line in fh:  # text file-likes are iterable by-line!
        var1, var2 = line.split(",")  # line is a string
# file is now closed when you leave the with scope!
```

This works because `.split()` returns a list, which can be directly used for assignment (if you have an equal number of members!)

```py
>>> var1, var2 = "wooden bow, 10".split(",")
>>> var1
'wooden bow'
>>> var2
' 10'
```

Do note, that you'll want to do some cleanup too, such as making numbers into integers or similar

```py
>>> var2 = int(var2)
>>> var2
10
```

As commented, this may be a good case for a CSV (or JSON) structure!

You will almost-certainly also wish to add some error-handling, which could be as simple as checking that the line doesn't raise an Exception, as complex as verifying the content with a regular expression, both, or inbetween!

Comment: hi good explanation but when i try to use this i get an attribute error: var1, var2 = line.read().split(",")
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'

Comment: @some_user_3 just remove the `read()` part. It would be  `var1, var2 = line.split(",")`. When you do `for line in fh` you are already reading the line as text.

Comment: Oops, yeah; line is already a string! Updated

Comment: thats great thanks for the answer! very well explained!

Answer (score 0):

A comma-separated file, even one as simple as this, is a `csv` file.

```
import csv

with open('file.txt') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        var1, var2 = map(lambda s: s.strip(), row)
```

Comment: although this works it would have been nice to have an explanation (as i am a beginner) however thanks for the help! This knew found option will aid me in future programs!